# Approaching regression analysis given all correlation is low

Tags: modeling

A question on approaching regression analysis when all Y - X correlation is low; almost all |correlation| < 0.1

To give an outline of data I have:

- Y (Store sales by month); n>2000
- Xi (Macro-economic data, Store type (binary variable for each type), Marketing score(eg. numeric data such as brand awareness); about 15-ish in total

I tried running regression, checking multicollinearity (VIF), clustering (K-means), feature selection (forward/backward selection) but nothing is giving me a tangible result.

My management wants to see an analysis so 'insufficient data' is not a viable conclusion at the moment (they want to see "something") so would really love to know what options I have left in this case.

Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you plotted store sales by month against each of these variables to see the behavior of the variables? It may very well be that when you plot something, you discover a nonlinear trend, like a sinusoidal trend, or it may be that you discover nothing, which you can communicate to management with clear-cut plots.

Comment: Some prediction problems are [hopeless](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222179/how-to-know-that-your-machine-learning-problem-is-hopeless), and a boss living in Fantasyland does not change that. However, a lack of correlation between individual features and the outcome [hardly](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/642606/247274) implies that the problem is hopeless.

Comment: I tried plotting it and some variables did show non-linear trend (albeit very faintly) but most did not yield anything promising. I am thinking is it possible because my Y variable is actually a times-series type of variable and hence I would have to take that into a consideration. Would it be possible this might be the case? Just not sure what would be a 'sufficient' evidence to say the problem is unsolvable at the moment.

Comment: Interactions, time trends, lags...you can do so much. It might be that the data do not allow for particularly accurate predictions, though. Perhaps [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/222179/how-to-know-that-your-machine-learning-problem-is-hopeless) is a better duplicate.